# Qt with WinAPI MouseProc

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I need to track the cursor position on the screen, for this I use a function from WinAPI

```
// code from Qt(!) project
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

MyClass *myclass;

static HHOOK hHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {   
    switch( wParam )
    {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        POINT p;
        GetCursorPos(&p);                   
        myclass->setState(QPoint(p.x,p.y),myclass->getParent()); // setCursor
        break;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
    //in the class constructor
    hHook = (HHOOK) ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, (HOOKPROC)MouseProc, GetModuleHandle(0),0) ;
```

This works, but sometimes the program crashes on exit. If comment out the last line, the program never crashes, but the mouse is not tracked. I don't know WinApi, so the error may be obvious

edit 1:

I know how to get the coordinates, but the problem is that the program crashes after exiting, if using WinAPI

edit 2:
thanks Nurav, the error is it, after clicking I delete the application, and if move the mouse, this function will be called, in which I refer to the children of the window

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to understand, what's happening. The *"crash"* is likely not related to the code you posted. You still need to remove those C-style casts; your code should compile without them. If it doesn't then you have just discovered a bug.

Comment: @IInspectable see change

Comment: That's still completely opaque information, and cannot be possibly seen by looking at the question. This isn't what we expect a [mcve] to be. Also, please don't accept an answer that doesn't answer your question. Future visitors will rely on on your accepted answer to actually solve the issue. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62624125/1889329) doesn't.

Comment: Inside the `case WM_MOUSEMOVE:` i want to print my `mouse is moving` in a textbox presnt in my ui , but i am not able to do so  , because my `MouseProc function` is static and wont be able to access non static members.                 any way i can use `ui->textbox->append("mouse is moving")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an use `GetCursorPos()` funtion for this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(wParam)
    {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        POINT p;
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        sprintf(msgbuf, "My coordinates is (%d,%d)\n", p.x,p.y);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
        break;
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos).
edit 1:

If it is its own win32 window, this is a feasible solution. But if it is another window you can not use this!

Comment: Sure, one *could* do that. But that leads into a problem you haven't answered: *When* should you call `GetCursorPos`? A low-level mouse hook calls into your hook procedure whenever there is input to be handled. How do you incorporate that behavior into your proposed solution?

Comment: @Nurav see change

Comment: If you want to monitor mouse movement over your window, there's no need to call `GetCursorPos` at all. The [WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove) message already passes you the coordinates. In the rare case that you do need the coordinates in screen space, just call [ClientToScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clienttoscreen).

Comment: @Artem072 Are you releasing the mouse hook before you exit the program?

Comment: @Yes, the maybe error is in this, after a click I delete the application, and if move the mouse, this function will be called

Comment: @Artem072 see [`UnhookWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unhookwindowshookex)

Comment: @IInspectable in the case of `WH_MOUSE_LL`, screen coordinates are provided in an [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msllhookstruct) struct via the hook procedure's `lParam`.

Comment: @rem That's true, though I'm almost positive that I was commenting on different code than there is now. The comment seems to be a left over of that.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau thanks, I checked if the application instance was deleted, but this solution is more elegant

Comment: Inside the case WM_MOUSEMOVE: i want to print my mouse is moving in a textbox presnt in my ui , but i am not able to do so , because my MouseProc function is static and wont be able to access non static members. any way i can use ui->textbox->append("mouse is moving")